# Populate input fields in a child component nested within a <form> in the parent component using Redux Connect

Tags: reactjs

I am using `@Connect` to provide the `CreateUser` component with the data needed when updating a person. In the `renderPersonalInfoFields()` function all of the input fields are rendered and automatically populated with the current value from the state (for example `contact.firstName`). The issue is I also need to populate the `bagReordering.url` field in the child component `UserHierarchy`. I have tried to set `bagReordering` in `componentWillReceiveProps()` but its not working. What am I doing wrong?

CreateUser.jsx

```
export default class CreateUser extends React.PureComponent {

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        currentLead: state.users.currentLead,
        authentication: state.authentication,
        loggedInUserSettings: state.userSettings,
        users: {
            enterprise: state.users.associatedUsers.ROLE_ENTERPRISE,
            branch: state.users.associatedUsers.ROLE_BRANCH,
            sales: state.users.associatedUsers.ROLE_SALES_REP
        },
        user: state.users.currentUser,
        loading: loadingSelector(state),
        selectableTags: state.users.selectableTags,
        availablePrograms: state.users.availablePrograms,
        getUserInfo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        createdUserEmail: selector(state, 'contact.email'),
        bagReordering: state.users.currentUser.bagReordering
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
        change,
        getAssociatedUsers: userActions.getAssociatedUsers,
        inviteUser: userActions.inviteUser,
        getSelectablePrograms: userActions.getSelectablePrograms,
        getAvailablePrograms: userActions.getAvailablePrograms,
        getLead: userActions.getLead,
        getUser: userActions.getUser,
        updateUser: userActions.updateUser,
        getUserInfo: userSettingsActions.getUserInfo,
    };

    @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
    @reduxForm({
        form: 'userCreation',
        validate,
        enableReinitialize: true,
    })

    renderForm = () => {
        const { isEditing } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="col">
                <h4 className="p-b-md">{this.getContactInfoTitle()}</h4>
                <Field
                    id="contact.firstName"
                    name="contact.firstName"
                    type="text"
                    label="First Name"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    component={TextField} />
                <Field
                    id="contact.lastName"
                    name="contact.lastName"
                    type="text"
                    label="Last Name"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    component={TextField} />
                <Field
                    id="contact.phone"
                    name="contact.phone"
                    type="tel"
                    label="Telephone number (optional)"
                    component={TextField} />
                <Field
                    disabled={isEditing}
                    id="contact.email"
                    name="contact.email"
                    type="email"
                    label="Email address"
                    spellCheck="false"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    autoCapitalize="off"
                    component={TextField} />
            </div>
        );


    }

    renderUserHierarchy = () => {
        const { authentication, isEditing, users, user, loggedInUserSettings } = this.props;
        return (
            <UserHierarchy
                isEditing={isEditing}
                enterprises={users.enterprise}
                branches={users.branch}
                salesReps={users.sales}
                loggedInUserRole={authentication.role}
                loggedInUser={loggedInUserSettings.currentUserInfo || null}
                user={user}
                bagReordering={user.bagReordering} />
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, submitting, isEditing, loading } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                { this.renderTopBreadcrumbs() }
                <div className="mainAdmin__content">
                    <h2 className="p-b-md">{isEditing ? 'Edit User' : 'Add User'}</h2>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
                        { this.renderUserHierarchy() }
                        <Divider />
                        { this.renderForm() }
                        <button type="submit" className="btn lg" disabled={submitting}>{isEditing ? 'Save' : 'Add User'}</button>
                    </form>
                    { this.renderModal() }
                    { loading && <Loading fullPage /> }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

UserHierarchy.jsx

```
export default class UserHierarchy extends React.PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
        isEditing: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
        onDirectParentChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        onRoleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        user: PropTypes.object,
        enterprises: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
        branches: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
        salesReps: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
        loggedInUserRole: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        loggedInUser: PropTypes.object,
        bagReordering: PropTypes.object,
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        user: null,
        enterprises: [],
        branches: [],
        salesReps: [],
        loggedInUser: { },
        bagReordering: { }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // do stuff
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ bagReordering: nextProps.bagReordering });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            userType,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            enterprise,
            userTypeOptions
        } = this.state;
        const { isEditing, user, loggedInUserRole } = this.props;

        if (isEditing && !user) {
            return null;
        }
        const selectedUserType = userType;

        return (
            <div className="m-b-md">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col col-50">
                        <Dropdown
                            label="User Class"
                            placeholder="User Class"
                            data={userTypeOptions}
                            selected={selectedUserType}
                            extraClassNames="createUsersHeader__filters"
                            onSelect={this.handleSwitchUserType} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    {
                        <div className="col col-50 m-t-md error">
                            { this.renderBagReorderingLink() }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    renderBagReorderingLink = () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
        const { userType, enterprise } = this.state;

        return (
                <Field
                    ref={this.bagReorderingURLRef}
                    disabled={disableInput}
                    id="bagReordering.url"
                    name="bagReordering.url"
                    type="text"
                    label="Bag Reordering URL"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    component={TextField} />
        );
    };

}
```

Comment: are you not using renderBagReorderingLink in your render method?

Comment: @avinash I am but when I removed the wrong code when I was editing it to post here. Nice catch, thanks.